# excel function to change the data based on value

Tags: excel, function, date

[image: Excel sheet]

If I have the above excel sheet . I need to define function to automatically :
set the expiry date column as the same date format of the production date

```
                             expiry date =production date + 2 months if the value="A"
                             expiry date =production date + 7 days if the value="B"
                             expiry date =production date + 15 days if the value="C"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most basic way, put this in C2...

```
=IF(A2="A",B2+60,IF(A2="B",B2+7,IF(A2="C",B2+15,"Error")))
```

I have put the `Error` there just in case there's something else than A, B or C. I'm also assuming that 2 months is 60 days.

If you have a lot of values, I would suggest that you use a reference table such as:

```
Value   Days
A       60
B       7
C       15
```

Let's say that table is in the range J1:K4, then I'd advise using this instead in C2:

```
=IFERROR(B2+VLOOKUP(A2,$J$1:$K$4,2,0),"Error")
```

Comment: thanks. But i want this column as date not number . I edited my qustion

Comment: @user2792748 Dates are numbers. If you get the result as numbers, just format the column C to Date.